# Multiple image loaders one page

Tags: jquery

I have a page with multiple images and I want to use a loader to make it look better whilst all images are loading.

**The problem:** Only the first loading image is hiding to make way for the actual image and the rest are not hiding

HTML:

```
<img src="/images/loaders/loader.gif" id="imgLoader">
<img src="/path/to/image1.jpg" class="sideImage">
<img src="/images/loaders/loader.gif" id="imgLoader">
<img src="/path/to/image2.jpg" class="sideImage">
<img src="/images/loaders/loader.gif" id="imgLoader">
<img src="/path/to/image3.jpg" class="sideImage">
<img src="/images/loaders/loader.gif" id="imgLoader">
<img src="/path/to/image4.jpg" class="sideImage">
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#imgLoader').show();
    var totalImages = $(".sideImage").length;
    var iLoaded = 0;
    $(".sideImage").each(function (){
        $(this).bind("load", function(){
            iLoaded++;
            if(iLoaded == totalImages){
                $('#imgLoader').hide();
            }
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr("src"));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `id`s should be unique

Comment: Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes not IDs - replace `imgLoader` ID with a class and target that.  It is not valid markup to have multiple identical IDs on the same page which is why your jQuery is only affecting the first image (because it doesn't expect to find more than one element with that ID on the page).  IDs are unique - no exceptions.  Classes should be used in any other situation.

Comment: Yup, you are correct, complete schoolboy error! Will accept when I can. Many thanks

Comment: @DarrenSweeney no problem, we all have those moments!